# In React Native how to get key in flatlist dynamically from json array

Tags: javascript, react-native

inside flat list  how to pass the key dynamically from JSON data

```
 Data:[{b:'1',c:'2',d:'3',e:'4'},                 
{b:'5',c:'6',d:'7',e:'8'}]



<Text style={{padding:10}}>{item.b}</Text>)}/>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Atleast show something that you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'; // Import FlatList

let data = [{b:'1',c:'2',d:'3',e:'4'},{b:'5',c:'6',d:'7',e:'8'}]; // Declare your array.

// Add FlatList into your view
<FlatList
   data={data}
   renderItem={this.renderListItem}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>

// In renderListItem, each object in the array will be passed in as a parameter.
renderListItem = ({ item }) => (
   <Text style={{padding:10}}>{item.b}</Text>)}/>
);
```